# Is the matrix ring $\mathbb{M}_n(R)$, $n\geq 2$, over a serial ring $R$ again serial?

Tags: modules, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. A right $R$-module $M$ is called **uniserial** if its submodules form a chain, i.e., for any two submodules $A,B\subseteq M$ either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$. The module $M_R$ is called **serial** if it's a direct sum of uniserial submodules. The ring $R$ is called **right (left) serial** if $R_R$ (${}_RR$) is serial. The ring $R$ is called **serial** if it's both left and right serial.

I ask whether the matrix ring $\mathbb{M}_n(R)$, $n\geq 2$, is also serial if $R$ is serial. I guess no. I guess that $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z}_4)$ is not serial despite the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a serial ring.

Comment: It's a bit hard to sort out different notions of seriality in google, but [this article in particular](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/1701.03579) says that "seriality is Morita invariant" and that would imply it is indeed inherited by matrix rings. Gena Puninski 'wrote the book' on serial rings so I'd be inclined to think it's true.